# Is it possible to build an program using Python with the GUI in JS/CSS? How to integrate the languages?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, user-interface

I’ve been programming with Python for some years,basically algorithms,CLI programs(with curses and urwid) and system management scripts. I’m experienced on using Tkinter but I just don’t find it as beautiful and design focused as e.g. CSS .I'm thinking about doing the hard work in Python(because is where I fell the most comfortable) and build the GUI with JS/CSS,like, buttons and animations in JS/CSS communicating with the Python behind it.  Is there a (well documented and active) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make Css/Js interact with python is either with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for making WebApps. The latter being a lot easier to grasp and do simple things (a micro framework). Django is a lot more robust and scalable. What they basically do is let you do all the backend in Python and through a templating language for Html, you can then include all the Js/Css you want. You can even use some frontend Js frameworks like React or Angular. There are lots of resources, just google it.

Hope that helps!

(just an IMO, I love django and the learning curve isn't really hard it just depends on how much you need to do for this app)

Comment: Django and Flask aren't the _only_ way. There are many web frameworks available for python.

Comment: Those two are definitely the best documented and more stable-updated. Just gave my two cents on the questions.

Comment: I agree. My point is that your use of the word "only" is misleading. I think the answer would be a little bit better if it said something like "the only way... is with a web framework such as Django or Flask ..."

Comment: @BryanOakley my bad there. Thought i wrote "only way i know".